# Label values that match values from other data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 3 data frames. One contains the whole set of numbers. Second and third data frames contain subsets of these numbers with a certain characteristic (type one or type two).  What I would like to do is to merge these data frames into one so that each number is checked on being type one or type two.

Example:

```
numbers <- c("+333","+334", "+335", "+443", "+444", "+445", "+553", "+554", "+555")
typeone <- c("+333","+334", "+335", "+443")
typetwo <- c("+335", "+443", "+444", "+445")
fs <- data.frame(numbers)        
to<- data.frame(typeone)
tt<- data.frame(typetwo)
```

Desired outcome after merging `fs`, `to` and `tt`:

```
   numbers    typeone    typetwo
1   333         yes 
2   334         yes 
3   335         yes        yes
4   443         yes        yes
5   444                    yes
6   445                    yes
7   553     
8   554     
9   555
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    data.frame(numbers = numbers,
               typeone = numbers %in% typeone, 
               typetwo = numbers %in% typetwo)
```

Then you can change new logical columns however you want.

Comment: Maybe this : `data.frame(numbers = numbers,
           typeone = ifelse(numbers %in% typeone,"yes","") ,
           typetwo = ifelse(numbers %in% typetwo, "yes", ""))`

Comment: Yes, it's easiest solution, but I don't see any advantages to using binary character string over logical. So I left it to the OP.

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin  You are right and this will also be easier for the user to subset (in needed) or index it later without having to convert it again to logical if you go through the "yes", "" route as suggested by somebody.  In addition, using `ifelse` could also slow down the process unnecessarily

Answer (score 2):

You can try a sequential merge. To have pretty column names out of the box, you could change names to `names(to) <- c("numbers", "typeone")` and similar for `tt`.

```
to$mhm <- "yes"
tt$mhm <- "yes"

out <- merge(fs, to, by.x = "numbers", by.y = "typeone", all.x = TRUE)
merge(out, tt, by.x = "numbers", by.y = "typetwo", all.x = TRUE)

  numbers mhm.x mhm.y
1    +333   yes  <NA>
2    +334   yes  <NA>
3    +335   yes   yes
4    +443   yes   yes
5    +444  <NA>   yes
6    +445  <NA>   yes
7    +553  <NA>  <NA>
8    +554  <NA>  <NA>
9    +555  <NA>  <NA>
```

Or place the datasets in a `list`, set the same column names, and use `Reduce` with `merge`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by= "numbers", all.x=TRUE), 
         list(fs, setNames(to, "numbers"), setNames(tt, "numbers")))
```

Comment: @akrun feel free to improve my question by editing this in.